# Save game scores to file and determine the "high score"

Tags: java

I have written a program that randomly selects a verb in Deutch and asks you for the Perfekt form. It continuously displays new verbs until you make a mistake. Then the program tells you your answer was incorrect and tells you how many points you have earned. The program also writes the number of points into the test.txt file and then re-reads that number from it.

Here is the code for my program (it works correctly as described above).

```
import java.util.Random;    
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Verben{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String glagol;
    String correct = "Correct!";
    String incorrect = "Incorrect!";
    int points = 0;
    boolean answer;

    File file = new File("test.txt");


    for(int i = 0; i <= points; i++){
        Random random = new Random();


        String verben[] = {"trinken", "lesen", "schwimmen", "sterben", "fahren"};
        String verbenAnswer[] = {"hat getrunken", "hat gelesen", 
               "hat geschwommen", "ist       gestorben", "ist gefahren"};
        glagol = verben[random.nextInt(verben.length)];
        System.out.println("Please enter correct form of verb!");
        System.out.println(glagol);
        String enter = Input.readLine();

        if(glagol.equals(verben[0]) && enter.equals(verbenAnswer[0])){
            answer = true;
            points += 1;
        }else if(glagol.equals(verben[1]) && enter.equals(verbenAnswer[1])){
            answer = true;
            points += 1;
        }else if(glagol.equals(verben[2]) && enter.equals(verbenAnswer[2])){
            answer = true;
            points += 1;
        }else if(glagol.equals(verben[3]) && enter.equals(verbenAnswer[3])){
            answer = true;
            points += 1;
        }else if(glagol.equals(verben[4]) && enter.equals(verbenAnswer[4])){
            answer = true;
            points += 1;
        }else{
            answer = false;
            points += 0;
        }

        if(answer == true){
            System.out.println(correct);
        }else{
            System.out.println(incorrect);
            System.out.println("You collected: " + points + "/" + (i+1));
        }   
    }

        try{
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
            output.println(points);
            output.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.printf("ERROR: %s\n", ex);
        }
         try{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            int point = input.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("Points: %d\n", point);
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println("ERROR");
        }

    }
}
```

How can I modify my code to permanently store all attempts in the test.txt file? How can I determine the all-time high score? After each run of the program I would like it to remind me "what is the all-time high score".

Comment: Your question is not clear. Is something working bad ? In which way ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, but I want to make addition to this program which allows me to store my results of a "test" and then show me all-time highest score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is...

Immediately after your for loop, determine the high score by reading your file line-by-line. To keep things simple we will assume that there is one score per line.

```
    // determine the high score
    int highScore = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null)                 // read the score file line by line
        {
            try {
                int score = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());   // parse each line as an int
                if (score > highScore)                       // and keep track of the largest
                { 
                    highScore = score; 
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
                // ignore invalid scores
                //System.err.println("ignoring invalid score: " + line);
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERROR reading scores from file");
    }
```

After determining the high score we can display the appropriate message.

```
    // display the high score
    if (points > highScore)
    {    
        System.out.println("You now have the new high score! The previous high score was " + highScore);
    } else if (points == highScore) {
        System.out.println("You tied the high score!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The all time high score was " + highScore);
    }
```

Finally we append the current score to the end of the file (on its own line).

```
    // append the last score to the end of the file
    try {
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        output.newLine();
        output.append("" + points);
        output.close();

    } catch (IOException ex1) {
        System.out.printf("ERROR writing score to file: %s\n", ex1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the all-time high-score at the beginning of the program then you need to read the file at the beginning of the program. Add all entries in the text-file into an ArrayList(or something similar), then find the greatest element in the list, display this. (Or keep track of the greatest element while reading the file, if you don't need the other scores later).

Also when you write a score to the file you need to make sure you add it to the end of the file, not overwriting the file.

Comment: I would suggest a `LinkedList` instead, it will be faster ton append a large number of elements.

Comment: I am still a beginner in java programming, so can you please write down how to do this  that you suggested?